# If Conditionals Inside of For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for insight into my if conditionals within my for loop. Currently, when I execute this function, the initial if conditional outside of the for loop runs, then the for loop starts. My test data has a length of 12, so the for loop runs the `if (length > 10)` conditional twice, and then runs the `else if (length == 10)` conditional. However, then it stalls and won't execute the next `else if` conditional (`else if (length > 3 && length <=10 && mergedGroup != [])`).

I think the issue lies with `mergedGroup != []` but I'm not sure how to say "don't execute this conditional unless length > 3 and length <= 10 and mergedGroup array isn't empty."

Assume all functions and variables inside this `executeFullRun` function are built and correct (I've tested them line by line in the console, just having issues putting them into one function to run all of them together).

Any insight?

```
function executeFullRun(players) {
  if (group1 != [] && group2!= []) {
    makeGroups(players);
  }
  var length = group1.length + group2.length;
  for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    if (length > 10) {
      while (group1.length + group2.length > 10) {
        winTribalImmunity(group1,group2);
        voteOffPreMerge(vulnerablePlayers);
        console.log('Group Vote');
        length -= 1;
        console.log(length);
      }
    } else if (length == 10) {
      if (group1.length + group2.length == 10) {
        mergeGroups(group1,group2);
        console.log('Merge Groups');
        console.log(length);
      }
    } else if (length > 3 && length <=10 && mergedGroup != []) {
      while (length > 3) {
        winIndividualImmunity(mergedGroup);
        voteOffPostMerge(vulnerableIndividuals);
        console.log('Individual Vote');
        length -= 1;
        console.log(length);
      }
    } else {
      if (length == 3) {
        winGame(mergedGroup);
        console.log('Winner!');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Assume all functions and variables inside this executeFullRun function are built and correct"* That's great to assume but without knowing the values of these so called correct variables how are we supposed to test if we have a solution that's correct? There are a number of functions that we have no clue what they return if anything. And what syntax is `group1 != []`? TypeScript? Never seen the likes in JavaScript.

Comment: it sounds like something is generating an error, possibly mergeGroups.  Have you debugged this using browser dev tools, ie stepped through each line of js seeing where it breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare an empty array to another empty array by doing `someExistingArray != []`.

They are completely different *object references* and therefore are never equal, regardless if contents and length are identical.

Check the array length instead

Try

```
if (length > 3 && length <=10 && mergedGroup.length) {
```

And

```
if (group1.length && group2.length) {
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct, however <anyarray> != [] so it should still trigger the conditional.

Comment: I didn't think to consider using `.length` as a condition. However, with your implementation, the function still stalls at 10 and runs out the for loop by continuing to do the same `else if (length == 10)` conditional.

Comment: Hard to help more without a [mcve]. Currently too many unknowns

Comment: I've edited the code to provide a ready to test example. You should be able to copy/paste it into a console and then run `fullSeason(contestants)`

Comment: froze my browser ... not interested in going through all those methods to find out where or why

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't freeze in Terminal. Hmm

Comment: I put it into jsfiddle and it timed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142983/discussion-between-septicrevo-and-charlietfl).